# User is not associated to Temperature. Sequelize Eager loading error

Tags: node.js, join, sequelize.js, associations, eager-loading

In my application every user can record many temperatures, but one temperature record should have only one user. I am trying to execute the following code and facing an 'User is not associated with Temperature' Error. Please review my code below and let me know where i have gone wrong.
This is my User model

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../connection');

var Temperature = require('./temperature');

var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },

    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    status: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'Active'
    },
    role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'Admin'
    }
});

User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Temperature, { as: 'temperatures' })
}

module.exports = User;
```

This is my Temperature model

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../connection');
const User = require('./users');

var Temperature = sequelize.define('Temperature', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    temperature: {
        type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    recordDateTime: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

Temperature.associate = (models) => {
    Temperature.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user' })
}

module.exports = Temperature;
```

I am getting error in running the following code

```
    Temperature.findAll({ include: User, raw:true})
    .then((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
    })
```

Can you anyone please help in figuring out this issue.
The associate functions in both the models are not executing.

Comment: can you check your database whether you have this constraint reflected there? I guess not

Comment: Yes i did. I have run the sql query for join in postgres. It is working there

Comment: No, not by making join query, try `SHOW CREATE TABLE <yourTableName>;` and see if you have a foreign key constraint in the create query

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add `userId` column into `Temperature` model schema, just define associations as you have already did and even if you want to add `userId` column in model schema the do it like below but must add it in migration file of your `Temperature` model schema like below

```js
userId: {
   type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
     allowNull: false,
     references: {
       model: 'Users', // <----- name of the table
       key: 'id'       // <----- primary key
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have mentioned it in the migrations as well. But still facing the issue